# Triggering jQuery("#collapseMenu").hide(); on pressing Esc key

Tags: javascript, jquery

As mentioned in WA-ARIA 1.0 keyboard interaction, I need to implement the following behaviour:

When a submenu is open and focus is on a menu item in that submenu:

- Escape or the Left Arrow key closes the submenu and returns focus to the parent menu item.

To achieve this, I added the following rudimentary javascript code to my page:

```
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    element = document.getElementById("spanID");
    menuElement = document.getElementById("bigMenu");
    if (element.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down") {
        element.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right";
        jQuery("#collapseMenu").hide();
        menuElement.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        sessionStorage.setItem("expand", false);
    }
}
```

That did not work, so it's not the correct way to go about things. Could someone point what is it that I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Why don't you use `$("#collapseMenu").hide();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're already using jQuery go all the way.

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 37) { // escape or left key

        var element = $("#spanID"),
            menuElement = $("#bigMenu");

        if (element.hasClass('glyphicon') && element.hasClass('glyphicon-menu-down')) {
            element.removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-right');
            $("#collapseMenu").hide();
            menuElement.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            sessionStorage.setItem("expand", false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("Escape");
        // Here is your code for hiding menu.
    }
};
```